# Sharing common 3rd party library for multiple projects

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to keep all common libraries (i.e. doctrine, twig, symphony .. ) outside the vendor directory and load them in my project. The goal is to keep the project related files in the project directory and keep the vendor directory or the common libraries outside the project to make project thinner so that all projects can share the same resource from a common location. Does symfony2 support this?

Comment: you have just made my day with the typo in your question :D :D

Comment: The whole symfony framework vendor folder weighs 36Mo. Do you have *THAT* many projects that makes you *NEED* to share them across projects? Moreover, each project may only work on a given release of each vendor. Modifying might lead to other application to crash. If it doesn't bother you, just modify the path in `autoload.php` where `$loader = require __DIR__ ...` to make it match with your global vendor directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make some links on your server? By making [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29), you can use several folders for your project, and in each one make a symbolic link in order to use a common `vendor/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `$loader->setUseIncludePath(true);` in `app/autoload.php`.

Using this Composer will load libraries from your vendor directory and if missing from system shared directories (including PEAR) defined in the PHP [include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) setting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much everyone. I think symbolic links would be the right choice for me. It is good to have the common libraries in a common place but also agree with “Touki” that projects could be dependent on some release of some vendors and that could potentially break other projects. But my requirement does not fall in to that category; so, I decided to keep the vendor directory in a common place.